# How to get the color in hex from graphcms to frontend with tailwind css (next js)

Tags: css, api, next.js, graphql, tailwind-css

```
import { getCategories } from '../services/graphql';

 const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getCategories()
            .then((result) => setCategories(result));
    }, []);
```

Here is the query for getCategories:

```
export const getCategories = async () => {
    const query = gql`
        query GetCategories{
            categories{
                title 
                slug
                metaDesc
                id
                color {
                    hex
                    css
                }
                featuredImage{
                    url
                    height
                    width
                }
            }
        }
    `
    const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);
    return result.categories;
}
```

So I want to get that hex color for background, with tailwind css how to get it.
Please help.

I have given that query, code and want to use the hex color for specific category background.